# Как составить JPQL-запрос для получение отсортированного списка сущностей из другой сущности, с которой есть связь ManyToMany?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Есть две сущности:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    
    @Id
    Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "a_b",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    )
    @OrderBy("name")
    Set<B> bs;
    
}
```

```
@Entity
public class B {
    
    @Id
    Integer id;

    String name;
    
}
```

Я хочу получить список сущностей **B**, которые привязаны к сущности **A**. Вообще, обычно это делается довольно легко:

```
SELECT a.bs FROM A a WHERE a.id=:id
```

но проблема в том, что мне ещё нужна сортировка сущностей **B** в списке результатов. Вот такой код работать не будет:

```
SELECT a.bs FROM A a WHERE a.id=:id ORDER BY a.bs.name ASC
```

потому что нельзя получить свойство сущности при обращении к списку сущностей *(единственное доступное свойство у `a.bs` - это size)*. Проблема осложняется ещё и тем, что в классе **B** нет поля **A**, а поэтому я не могу сделать вот так:

```
SELECT b FROM B b WHERE b.a.id=:id
```

Итак. Надо получить отсортированный список сущностей **B** по id сущности **A**. Я составил такой JPQL-запрос:

```
SELECT a.bs AS b FROM A a WHERE a.id=:id ORDER BY b.name ASC
```

Но при компиляции возникает ошибка:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'b.name'
```

хотя при редактировании кода IDEA ошибок не показывала.

Как мне следует изменить запрос, чтобы получить отсортированный список сущностей **B**?

Comment: Используйте JOIN - `SELECT a.bs FROM A a JOIN a.bs c where c.id= :id`

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov да, работает. Вот такой запрос сделал: `SELECT a.bs FROM A a JOIN a.bs b WHERE a.id=:Id ORDER BY b.name`. Дубликаты только возвращает блин. Ну уж попробую разобраться:)

Comment: Господа, кто ставит тревоги, проблема не вызвана опечаткой, не надо ставить неправильные тревоги!

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov странно, теперь дубликаты не возвращает и всё работает нормально. Видимо, я где-то накосячил и неправильно запрос написал. Оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ, я вам галку поставлю (но долго ждать не буду, завтра сам ответ напишу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мою задачу решает предложенный [@Sergey Mitrofanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179525/sergey-mitrofanov) запрос:

```
SELECT b FROM A a JOIN a.bs b WHERE a.id=:id ORDER BY b.name
```